# OCR Tesseract configuration

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I am working with Tesseract to extract vocabulary lists out of images.

The lists consist out of 2 different languages. Unfortunately there is only whitespace between lang1 and lang2 (maybe 3 or 4 blank characters).

Is there a way to define, which string to take to separate the two from each other.

The list could look like the following:

house, building    Haus, Gebäude
tree    Baum
...

Also I have problems to get a linebreak after each word-pair.

Thanks!

Edit:
I run this command

```
tesseract bilder/screenshot1.png output/screenshot1 -l swe+deu
```

to extract all entries from this picture

[image: Swedish - German wordlist]

As you can see, there is no clear separator between the values. As output I get this

```
nej nein

jaha aha

Vad talar du för språk? Welche Sprachen sprichst du?
vad för welche, was für

tala (talar, talade, talat) sprechen

språk (-et, —, -en) Sprache

japanska japanisch

engelska englisch

Du då? Und du?

då da, dann, damals, als

bara nur

lite ein bisschen

verb (-et, —, en) Verb

position (—en, -er, -erna) Stellung, Position
OBS (= observera) NB, Achtung!

fråga (-n, -or, -orna) Frage
```

which is quiet good. But I don't know how to seperate the string of each line in two strings because of the missing usable separator.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Tesseract API and try to separate the words by calling the method `WordFontAttributes` of the class `ResultIterator` to determine if one word is bold or not. [This](https://gist.github.com/angeldm/4663739) GitHub gist shows how the method is used.